# question about using "specifically"

Tags: adverbs, phrases

> The Bill to Address the Humanitarian Health Crisis passed the first of two votes in Venezuela's unicameral National Assembly on Tuesday. After a health crisis is declared, Venezuela can then receive medications as a form of aid from other countries, **specifically in Latin America and Europe**. Venezuela would also be allowed to request assistance from the World Health Organization.

Source: 
http://www.upi.com/Top_News/World-News/2016/04/06/Venezuela-seeks-foreign-medical-aid-amid-health-crisis-genocide/1691459953798/

I suppose the meaning is that the 'other countries' in question are in Latin America and Europe. But does the sentence really work with the intended meaning? 
Could 'specifically in Latin America and Europe' be used to postmodify 'other countries' adjectivally?

Gratefully,

Navi.

Comment: I expanded your quote for additional context.

Comment: could receive medicines, specifically FROM Latin American and Europe.

Comment: That is a translation or not properly edited/written. It should read: Venezuela can then receive medicines as a form of aid from other countries, specifically in Latin America and Europe. i.e. aid from countries in Latin America and Europe.

Answer (score 1):

[*specific*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/specific) by definition points to limited items in a broader group. So in context *other countries* refers to those *in Latin America and Europe*.

Also checking the next sentence, the reference to the "World Health Organization" indicates the worldwide support, beyond the regions already mentioned.